# Delete a DataTable row, source of selected DataGridView row, on button click

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have this DataTable called `ProductTable`that have 3 columns that serves as the source for the DataGridView `ProductGrid`.

When clicking on the button `DeleteRow`, the user should delete the row in `ProductTable` that correspond the selected row in `ProductGrid`

I tried with

```
Private Sub DeleteRow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteRow.Click

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 100
        Try
            ProductTable.Rows(i).Delete()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next

End Sub
```

But I'm missing something obvious : The condition that allows me to pick the row in the DataTable that would correspond to `ProductGrid.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString()`.

But I don't know how to do it, as `ProductTable.Rows(i).Columns(0).Value` doesn't work since `Columns` isn't a member of the `Row` object.

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: "correspond the selected row in ProductGrid", How do you decide which row is selected? is the button DeleteRow inside the ProductGrid?

Comment: The selected row is the row on which the user clicked.
DeleteRow isn't inside ProductGrid, but bellow in the same userform.

Comment: How do you know which row is selected when user clicks a button outside the ProductGrid? Is there a checkbox in every row? Can you show with screenshot? It would be way easier if you add a new column so that a delete button corresponds to each row.

Comment: I added a screenshot, with redacted content of course. The blue cells correspond to the selected row in the datagridview.

Comment: Is the grid using a DataSource?   Show how the grid is getting its data.

Comment: Quite simple : `ProductGrid.DataSource = ProductTable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a problem deleting a row from the bound `DataTable` using the grids “selected” row index if the grid is “Sorted or Filtered”. I am betting the wrong rows will get deleted from the `DataTable` when the grid is sorted or filtered.

To fix this, I suggest using the grids `DataBoundItem` from the selected row. This should ensure the proper row is removed from the `DataTable`.  Something like below…

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
  if (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count() > 0) Then
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
    If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
      row.DataBoundItem.Delete
      ' You can also directly delete the row from the grids rows collection
      ' which will automatically map to the proper row in the table
      'DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, but I didn't know about the DataBoundItem objet, thanks !

Comment: I cannot get this to compile with Option Strict on. It is the `row.DataBoundItem.Delete` It seems to need a cast but I can't figure to what. The MS docs show the Grid bound to an ArrayList of a class and the cast is to the underlying class.

Comment: @Mary I am guessing there is some “conversion/widening/narrowing” or unseen casting between the `DataGridViewRow` and the tables `DataRow` we are deleting. I am just guessing as this appears to be the only “conversion/narrowing” going on that would cause the compiler to complain. Fortunately, you can use the commented line of code below. `DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index)` It works with Option Strict on.

Comment: For Option Strict on (which it should be) the line should read... `DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Delete()`

Comment: The commented area worked for me DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index). :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete single selected row

```
DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Delete()
```

Comment: I want to delete a DataTable row, not the DataGridView one :)